# Widget behaviour in observer pattern

Tags: android, widget, observer-pattern

I am writing a program to do home automation. I have a fragment which, when you interact with it, will toggle a remote device. Upon receiving a response from the device, I update an imageview in the fragment to reflect the state of the device(light bulb on/light bulb off). I also have a widget which does the same.

I am using AsyncTasks to handle making the remote calls. In order to achieve consistency between the widget and the fragment(for example if i switch off the light using the widget, the image in the fragment also gets updated) I am having everything that sends that toggle request register itself(in the onUpdate of the widget, and in the onCreateView of the fragment ) as a listener to other toggle events. I imagined that this would leave me with 2 listeners. The fragment, and the widget. However, in practice, I'm seeing 5 or 6 instances of the widget, and I'm not sure why. Here is my listener code.

```
public class LightToggleTask extends SparkAPITask {
private static String api_path = "toggle";
private static HashMap<OnTaskCompleted, Context> statusListeners = new HashMap<OnTaskCompleted, Context>();

public LightToggleTask(String deviceID,OnTaskCompleted listener, Context context) {
    super(deviceID, api_path, listener, context);
    statusListeners.put(listener, context);//adding listeners to the hashmap
}

public static void registerForToggleEvent(OnTaskCompleted listener, Context context){
    statusListeners.put(listener, context);
}

@Override
    public void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray){
        Set entries = statusListeners.entrySet();
        Iterator i = entries.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){

            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)i.next();
            Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute() -> Notifying observer that task has completed: " + entry.toString());
            ((OnTaskCompleted)entry.getKey()).onTaskCompleted(jsonArray, (Context)entry.getValue());
        }
    }
```

What i'm getting in the logs is stuff like this:

```
11-05 10:37:51.470  25437-25437/com.example.hcp.home_control_prototype I/SparkAPITask﹕ onPostExecute() -> Notifying observer that task has completed: com.example.hcp.home_control_prototype.WidgetProvider@4260a528=android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@426cfa68
11-05 10:37:51.490  25437-25437/com.example.hcp.home_control_prototype I/SparkAPITask﹕ onPostExecute() -> Notifying observer that task has completed: com.example.hcp.home_control_prototype.WidgetProvider@425de730=android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@426cfa68
11-05 10:37:51.490  25437-25437/com.example.hcp.home_control_prototype I/SparkAPITask﹕ onPostExecute() -> Notifying observer that task has completed: com.example.hcp.home_control_prototype.WidgetProvider@42623750=android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@426cfa68
11-05 10:37:51.500  25437-25437/com.example.hcp.home_control_prototype I/SparkAPITask﹕ onPostExecute() -> Notifying observer that task has completed: com.example.hcp.home_control_prototype.WidgetProvider@426cfa50=android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@426cfa68
11-05 10:37:51.500  25437-25437/com.example.hcp.home_control_prototype I/SparkAPITask﹕ onPostExecute() -> Notifying observer that task has completed: com.example.hcp.home_control_prototype.WidgetProvider@426305c8=android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@426cfa68
11-05 10:37:51.500  25437-25437/com.example.hcp.home_control_prototype I/SparkAPITask﹕ onPostExecute() -> Notifying observer that task has completed: com.example.hcp.home_control_prototype.WidgetProvider@42691b20=android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@426cfa68
11-05 10:37:51.500  25437-25437/com.example.hcp.home_control_prototype I/SparkAPITask﹕ onPostExecute() -> Notifying observer that task has completed: ToggleLightFragment{42640d38 #0 id=0x7f09005b}=null
```

I'm probably doing something very dumb. I am new to android development and I'm not sure what I've missed. It appears as though even though I only have the one widget, when i register it as a listener, it returns a different key each time? Is there a better way for me to be doing this?

Comment: How often are you calling `new LightToggleTask()`? Are you also calling `registerForToggleEvent()` after calling the constructor? If so, I could see how you would get duplicates, then a solution would be to either remove your call to `registerForToggleEvent` or remove the `statusListeners.put` call in your constructor.

Comment: oh my god how did I not realize I was also adding listeners in the constructor. I guess I've looked at this code so often my eyes just glazed over it. That being said, do you happen to know why I'm getting a different ID every time it's being registered? Even though I only have the one widget?